# Memory runs out and PC freezes

Tags: memory, ram, out-of-memory, resources

I have been having issues playing video games on my PC, as I keep running out of RAM (8GB).

When I run out of RAM, my displays and everything else freezes, except playing audio keeps looping. I have to force a shutdown and I often get banned from the game before I can rejoin.

I want to solve this issue in some way, I'll write down my options in the order I prefer them in:

1. Prevent my PC from running out of RAM by reducing RAM usage safely somehow. Windows apparently already does this, scaling its RAM usage when running out.
2. Another option would be to only crash the game, not the whole OS when running out of memory. Some kind of script that kills the process using the most memory would do. This would at least prevent me from getting banned every time I run out of memory.
3. How viable is it to run a swapfile on a 130MBps max speed with 26ms delay HDD? Would I be able to keep playing or at least kill the game from htop running on my second display while running on swap memory?

Comment: things freezing and audio looping is not really a typical symptom of running out of RAM. How do you *know* that you're running out of RAM? By the way, windows isn't magic or any less RAM hungry than your other operating system – Linux I guess?

Comment: You should **always** add a swap to your system, regardless of RAM size or storage speed.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I always have bpytop running on my secondary screen, when RAM usage gets to 7.60GB / 7.68GB bpytop and the whole system freezes. Windows also isn't magic, it appears to unload UI components from RAM to keep the system up as long as possible. This hugely slows down the system, but is better than nothing. Yes, Windows is generally more RAM hungry than Linux, but when it comes to running out of RAM, Windows is able to scale itself down and Linux (by default) is not.

Comment: @mashuptwice But is my about-50-times-slower-than-ram HDD fast enough to run the game? Or have I misunderstood swapping? In my understanding when the game runs out of RAM, it leaks over to my hard drive, doesn't it? Or does the system swap background stuff that I don't need? Because in this case, a swapfile could be used effectively.

Comment: @tempacc Linux does exactly the same as windows there: swapping out unused memory, flushing file system buffers to disk, you name it. It's really no different.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Alright, I've clearly misunderstood swapfiles, thinking it's a different concept from paging. If you post an answer about swapfiles, I'll mark it as the correct answer.